# ACF Google Map - Issue with Info Window

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have a google map integrated into my site, which works great.

I am trying to find out how to add an infoWindow, when the marker is clicked.

I have the below from Advanced Custom Fields:

```
    <?php 

$location = get_field('map');

if( !empty($location) ):
?>
<div class="acf-map" style="border:10px solid #1a1a1a;">
    <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have also added the required JS and CSS from http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

Hopefully someone has a quick solution to this!
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing content in the inner HTML of the div

```
 <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">CONTENT NEEDS TO BE ADDED HERE</div>
```

Because ACF JS uses the content in the div and put in the Popup window .

```
// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response!

That worked, It now has a popup! Thank you very much!
I can now just add some Custom fields to let the user add information for each marker.

+1 for you dude, thanks again!

Comment: I was going to, It made me wait 5 minutes before I could haha